# $100(1-\alpha)$% confidence interval

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, sampling

$100(1-\alpha)$% confidence interval for population mean $\bar Y$
$$\bar y\pm Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\mathbb v(\bar y)}$$

- Why is this $Z$ value depending on $\alpha$ important for constructing confidence interval?
- Isn't our target  to minimize the standard error? Then, why do i need to concern about $\alpha$ ?

Comment: The minimizing is achieved by using $\bar{y}$ as an estimator. We need some measure of the likely reliability of this estimator.

Comment: @AndréNicolas for estimating $\bar Y$, have i other estimators except $\bar y$ ? How can i get the reliability? By using an appropriate sampling procedure so that it will minimize the variance?

Comment: For underlying distribution normal, $\bar{y}$ is best by all the measures of best I am familiar with. To get a measure of reliability compute a confidence interval. $\alpha=0.05$ is the most traditional choice.